# how to group_by a query by date and sum 2 others fields

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

My model looks like this :

```
class PostMetric(models.Model):
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    comments = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like to get the sum of likes and comments for each day (note that i need to transform the datetimefield to datefield (probably using Cast?):

```
   date       engagement (likes+comments)
 2/5/2017         26
 3/5/2017         29
```

I tried to use : Cast, annotate, aggregate and even rawsql and extra/select functions but with no success.

I think that i need to add an aggregation based to this query :

```
PostMetric.annotate(engagement=Sum('likes') + Sum('comments')).annotate(date_only=Cast('created_at', DateField()))
```

Comment: post your best shot please

Comment: @e4c5 : i edited my post

Comment: read this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: thanks @Gahan for your suggestion but i wouldn't ask before reading this article

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emulate a group_by query then you can use the `.values` method.

```
PostMetric.objects.values('created_at').annotate(engagement=Count('likes')+Count('comments')
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it works: `PostMetric.objects.filter(my_filter).annotate(date_only=TruncDay('created_at')).values('date_only').annotate(engagement=Sum('likes') + Sum('comments'))`